# PostgreSQL drop view in case of unknown whether materialized or not

Tags: postgresql, view, materialized-view, drop-table

I'm trying to drop a view, of which I cannot assure whether it is a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` or a `VIEW`.

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS myview;
```

throws an error, if `myview` is a MATERIALIZED VIEW and vice versa. What I am looking for is drop statement (or function) that does not care about if it has to drop a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` or a `VIEW`.

(hint: there seems to be neither `drop` nor `drop-view` tag, therefore `drop-table`)

Answer (score 2):

My solution at this point is a function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dropview(IN view_schema TEXT, IN view2drop TEXT)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS 
$$
DECLARE drop_stmnt VARCHAR;
BEGIN
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN relkind = 'm' THEN 'MATERIALIZED VIEW'
        WHEN relkind = 'v' THEN 'VIEW'
    END
FROM pg_class
WHERE relname = view2drop
INTO drop_stmnt;

EXECUTE 'DROP ' || drop_stmnt || ' IF EXISTS ' || view_schema ||'.'|| view2drop || ';';
END;
$$;
```

so that with

```
SELECT dropview('myschema', 'myview');
```

doesn't have to care about `MATERIALIZED VIEW` or `VIEW`.